# JPA, get data from @ManyToMany relation generated table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have classes:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Role> roles = new LinkedList<>();
}
@Entity
public class Role {
}
```

Jpa/Hibernate generated three tables for those classes:

- User (id)
- Role (id)
- User_Role (user_id, role_id)

Now I would like to get list of user with concrete role f.e.: role_id = 4

How Can I achive this? There is no Entity like User_Role, so I would ask for data?

Comment: Use a query: `select distinct u from User u join u.roles r where r.id = 4`. Note: it's a **list** of roles, so name your field `roles`, not `role`. Read the manual: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql. You could also make the association bidirectional, load the role by ID, and get its list of users. All that is explained in the manual.

Comment: Thanks man for pointing me this tutorial. It is great. Your answer is also great. It works. If You could post it as an answer I would close this issue.
`role` was misspelled.

Comment: I would recommend that you do not use ManyToMany, but dissolve it so the mapping table is also an Entity. If gives you better control, and can also give you better performance. I recommend that you check this video by one of the Hibernate engineers https://vimeo.com/190275665#t=1700 (like to the relationship section)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), I've solved this issue.

Bellow is working code:

```
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public static List<User> findByRole(Role role) {
    Query query = JPA
        .em()
        .createQuery("select distinct u from User u join u.roles r where r.id =:role_id", User.class)
        .setParameter("role_id", role.id);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```